# Load Lakka(linux based) onto the Intel Compute Stick?

Tags: linux, intel

Okay, so I have recently purchased an [Intel Compute Stick](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/compute-stick/intel-compute-stick.html) and I have noted that it can either take Windows 10 or Linux operating systems. My main goal was to us [Lakka](http://www.lakka.tv/), a linux based retro console, in order to retro-game from the stick. But I haven't found any way to do this. I have loaded the img onto a drive(would not boot.) And I tried to select the boot device manually but to no avail. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Were you already in the UEFI menu (apparently you need to press `F2`)?

Comment: @phk yes. That didn't do much so I went through F10 to get to boot options. The drive didn't show.

Comment: "USB Boot" is enabled? Did you try the flash drive already at another machine (some are not bootable, especially quite old ones).

Comment: @phk I have USB boot enables, and I have tried this process with multiple drives so far. PS Thank you for taking the time to help. :)